# Print the line between specific pattern

Tags: python, python-2.6

I want to print the lines between specific string, my string is as follows:

```
my_string = '''
##start/file1
file/images/graphs/main
file/images/graphs
file/graphs

##start/new
new/pattern/symbol
new/pattern/

##start/info/version
version/info/main
version/info/minor

##start
values/key
values
...
... '''
```

In this string i want to search for "main" and print it as:

```
##start/file1/file/images/graphs/main
##start/info/version/version/info/main
```

How can i do this?
I tried to find the lines between two ##start and search for main.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
def get_mains(my_string):
    section = ''

    for line in my_string.split('\n'):
        if line[0:7] == "##start":
            section = line
            continue
        if 'main' in line:
            yield '/'.join([section, line])

for main in get_mains(my_string):
    print main
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this with Python's Regular Expressions Parser called regex for short.

Basically, regex is this whole language for searching through a string for certain patterns. If I have the string `'Hello, World'`, it would match the regex pattern `'llo, Wor'`, because it contains an ell followed by an ell followed by an o followed by a comma and a space and a capital double-you and so on. On the surface it just looks like a substring test. The real power of regex comes with special characters. If I have the string `'Hello, World'` again, it also matches the pattern `'Hello, \w\w\w\w\w'`, because `\w` is a special character that stands for any letter in the alphabet (plus a few extras). So `'Hello, Bobby'`, `'Hello, World'`, `'Hello, kitty'` all match the pattern `'Hello, \w\w\w\w\w'`, because `\w` can stand in for any letter. There are many more of these 'special characters' and they are all very useful. To actually answer your question,

I constructed a pattern that matches

```
##start\textICareAbout
file_I_don't_care
file_I_don't_care
file_I_care_about\main
```

which is

```
r'(##start{line}){line}*?(.*main)'.format(line=r'(?:.*\n)')
```

The leading r makes the string a raw string (so we don't have to double backslash newlines, see the linked webpage). Then, everything in parenthesis becomes a group. Groups are peices of texts that we want to be able to recall later. There are two groups. The first one is `(##start{line})`, the second one is `(.*main)`. The first group matches anything that starts with `##start` and continues for a whole line, so lines like
`##start/file1` or `##start/new`
The second group matches lines that end in main, because `.*` matches every character except newlines. In between the two groups there is `{line}*`, which means 'match any thing that is a complete line, and match any number of them'. So tying it all together, we have:
match anything that starts with `##start`, then we match any number of lines, and then we match any line that ends in main.

```
import re

# define my_string here

pattern = re.compile(r'(##start{line}){line}*?(.*main)'.format(line=r'(?:.*\n)'))

for match in pattern.findall(my_string):
    string = match[0][:-1]  # don't want the trailing \n
    string += '/'
    string += match[1]
    print string
```

For your example, it outputs

```
##start/file1/file/images/graphs/main
##start/new/version/info/main
```

So Regex is pretty cool and other languages have it too. It is a very powerful tool, and you should learn how to use it [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL).
Also just a side note, I use the .format function, because I think it looks much cleaner and easier to read, so
`'hello{line}world'.format(line=r'(?:.*\n)')` just becomes evaluated to `'hello(?:.*\n)world'`, and it would match

```
hello
Any Text Here. Anything at all. (just for one line)
world
```